# Half an oval shape in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have managed to create an oval shape in CSS. How do I half this **horizontally** now?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lejqovqy/

```css
.oval {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  border: 1px solid #1abc9c;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```

Comment: you might need a square http://jsfiddle.net/Lejqovqy/1/ or flat half oval from a rectangle http://jsfiddle.net/Lejqovqy/2/  border-radius: 100% 0 0 100%/50%; . -webkit- prefix is no longer needed by th way ;)   ... hmm horyzontal , like rotated ? http://jsfiddle.net/Lejqovqy/3/ swithch size value or transform:rotate(90deg);

Comment: Just check my answer, simple and efficient with css only.

Comment: I updated my answer with 2 versions, one circle and one semi-circle, and that is better than svg as it just renders "as is" and no "image" is needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a half circle, and a semi-circle, with hover effect.

Edit

And a third approach, as Harry suggested, using pseudo element.

```css
.div1{
     display: inline-block;
     height:45px;
     width:90px;
     border: 1px solid #999;
     border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
     border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
}
.div2{
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 20px;
     height:30px;
     width:90px;
     border: 1px solid #999;
     border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
     border-radius: 50% / 100%;
     border-top-left-radius: 0;
     border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.div3 {
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     height:90px;
     width:180px;
     border: 1px solid #999;
     border-radius: 10px;
}
.div3:after{
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: 45px;
     left: 45px;
     height:30px;
     width:90px;
     border: 1px solid #999;
     border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
     border-radius: 50% / 100%;
     border-top-left-radius: 0;
     border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.div3:before{
     content: "-\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0o";
     position: absolute;
     top: 20px;
     left: 66px;
}
div:hover {
     background-color: #DDD;
}
div:hover:after {
     background-color: #BBB;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div><div class="div2"></div>
<br /><br />
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Comment: That's a good approach too and using a pseudo could avoid the need for extra elements. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @LGSon Can you explain where I'm going wrong here? https://jsfiddle.net/p8jfnwa0/4/ Thank you so much :)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk And here is a version using pseudo https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/p8jfnwa0/7/

Comment: @LGSon Many thanks for this, much tidier. See if I wanted to apply a hover to change the background colour of both shapes to black, how would I do this?

Comment: @LGSon - Wow, that is absolutely perfect. Many thanks for your patience, persistence and perspiration(?) throughout this fiddly task. Kudos!!

Answer (score 9):

**Using SVG:**

I would recommend you to use SVG for creating half oval shapes as it is a lot more easier than doing it with CSS. Below is a sample snippet which uses an absolutely positioned SVG element and an arc `path` to create the half oval.

```css
.oval {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-overflow: clip;
}
.oval svg, .shape svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.oval path, .shape path {
  stroke: #1abc9c;
  fill: transparent;
}
.oval path:hover{
  fill: #1abc9c;
}

/* for the full shape */
.shape {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-overflow: clip;
}
#bottom-oval:hover{
  fill: #1abc9c;
}
  
span{
  position: absolute;
  color: #1abc9c;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval">
  <svg viewBox='0 0 200 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <path d='M2,50 A98,48 1 1,0 198,50' />
  </svg>
</div>

<hr>

<!-- Just to illustrate the whole thing you're trying is possible with SVG -->
<div class="shape">
  <svg viewBox='0 0 200 150' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <path d='M2,8 2,92 A6,6 0 0,0 8,98 L80,98 M128,98 L192,98 A6,6 0 0,0 198,92 L198,8 A6,6 0 0,0 192,2 L8,2 A6,6 0 0,0 2,8' />
    <path d='M80,97 A24,20 1 1,0 128,97' id='bottom-oval'/>
  </svg>
  <span>+</span>
</div>
```

---

**Using CSS Borders and Clip Path:**

Another approach that could be adopted if you really want to use CSS borders is the `clip-path` along with inline SVG like in the below snippet. This just cuts out the top part of the ellipse and thus produces a half oval shape. This method can be useful if IE support is not required because `clip-path` is not supported in IE.

```css
.oval {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-overflow: clip;
  border: 1px solid #1abc9c;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
```

```html
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id='clipper' clipPathUnits='objectBoundingBox'>
      <path d='M0,1 0,0.5 1,0.5 1,1z' />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class='oval'></div>
```

**Using Radial Gradients:**

You could also use `radial-gradient` background image like in the below snippet to create semi oval shapes but the browser support for gradients in IE is only from IE10+ and the output also produces jagged edges which make it not really aesthetic. Due to those reasons, I wouldn't recommend this.

```css
.oval {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse 190px 90px at 50% 0%, transparent 48%, #1abc9c 48%, #1abc9c 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```

Comment: That's an excellent point I hadn't considered! Is it easy enough to `flip` this SVG? I'm trying to achieve something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/p8jfnwa0/

Comment: @michaelmcgurk: Yep, it can be flipped. Please check the updated snippet (first one).

Comment: That's absolutely perfect. Out of interest, if I was to hover over the oval, is it possible to fill it with that colour, even though it's a SVG? My knowledge here is slim to say the least :)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk: Oopss sorry, the page didn't refresh and so didn't note your comment. You mean the fill should be only for the half oval at the bottom? If that is the case then it is possible but would need slight tweaking of the approach.

Comment: Many thanks, Harry. Just taking it all in right now - wow, thank you so much for all your efforts here.

Answer (score 5):

Change your `border-radius` like this `border-radius:50% 0 0 50%;`

```css
.oval {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius:50% 0 0 50%;
  border-radius:0 0 50% 50%;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  border: 2px solid #1abc9c;
  border-top:0;
  border-right:0;
  border-left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I mean halved vertically. So it's just a semi-oval shape at the bottom left. No straight border either.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk can you show an image of what you are trying to do ?

Comment: It's exactly like this: https://jsfiddle.net/p8jfnwa0/ but so it still works in Firefox. You can see from this example it doesn't work in FF yet :) Thank you.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Try it now

Comment: That's great. But is it possible to just have the bottom shape and now the 2 long parallel lines?

Comment: Try it now @michaelmcgurk but it won't be as perfect as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

```css
.oval {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
  border-top-right-radius:0px;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  border: 1px solid #1abc9c;
}
```

```html
<div class="oval"></div>
```